# c2hs fun marshalling

Tags: haskell

I'm working on `ffi` bindings to the [Assimp library](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) using `c2hs`. I have a datatype `AiScene`, defined as follows (the details are unimportant):

```
data AiScene = AiScene
  { mFlags         :: SceneFlags
  , mMeshes        :: [AiMesh]
  , mMaterials     :: [AiMaterial]
  , mAnimations    :: [AiAnimation]
  , mTextures      :: [AiTexture]
  , mLights        :: [AiLight]
  , mCameras       :: [AiCamera]
  }
{#pointer *aiScene as AiScenePtr -> AiScene#}
```

Now I'm trying to write bindings to the following function:

```
const aiScene* aiImportFile( 
    const char* pFile, 
    unsigned int pFlags);
```

This is what I have so far:

```
{#fun aiImportFile as ^
  {`String', cFromEnum `SceneFlags'} -> `AiScene' peek*#}
```

Unfortunately I get a type error...

```
Couldn't match expected type `AiScene' against inferred type `()'
  Expected type: IO AiScene
  Inferred type: IO ()
```

Now if I go into the generated source and change the type:

```
aiImportFile'_ :: ((Ptr CChar) -> (CUInt -> (IO (Ptr ()))))      -- original
aiImportFile'_ :: ((Ptr CChar) -> (CUInt -> (IO (Ptr AiScene)))) -- fixed
```

Then the problem goes away. How can I get `c2hs` to do this automatically / what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edit: One thing I forgot to mention is that I have defined an instance of `Storable` for `AiScene`.

Comment: Your marshaller works for me with c2hs-0.16.2, OS X 10.6.  What version of c2hs are you using?

Comment: @John Interesting. I'm also using 0.16.2, but on Linux. I wonder what the problem could be. Something to do with cabal?

Comment: I don't think it's cabal-related.  It seems as though the foreign import call is wrong, which is very odd.  I wonder if the header file is getting munged during the CPP pass?  Run `c2hs --keep` and check to see if the declaration for `aiImportFile` is correct.  You could also try using `{#call ...#}` instead of a function hook, and write the marshalling wrapper manually.

Comment: @John when I run `c2hs --keep`, `Fun.i` has the declaration of `aiImportFile` exactly as it appears in the header file. If I decide to give up and use `call` then I think I'm going to just switch to hsc2hs. Which would be unfortunate since the only problem is that one pointer type.

Comment: @John Ok I think I've solved it for now. I defined the following: `with' x y = with x (y . castPtr)` and `peek' = peek . castPtr` and the type errors go away. I would like to find the root cause but this should do for now (I haven't actually tested it). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

community-wiki answer with the solution for posterity:

I defined the following: `with' x y = with x (y . castPtr)` and `peek' = peek . castPtr` and the type errors go away.